# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withConfig')" styled-components/react/rollup/babel

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, styled-components, rollup

Please help me out to solve a problem. I'm making my library for react apps using styled-components, react, storybook. Also have babel config and rollup for bundling. I'm really not sure about babel and rollup configs cuz I'm setting them myself for the first time.

When I'm checking how the lib works via storybook all is fine. But when I publish it on npm and trying to use it in another react project, created via npx create-react-app I'm constantly getting and error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withConfig')" in console and my app doesn't show anything.

Here you can see my .babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
        ],
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "alias": {
              "@src": ["./src"],
              "@components": ["./src/components"],
              "@utils": ["./src/utils"]
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "babel-plugin-styled-components",
          { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      { "ssr": true, "displayName": true, "preprocess": false }
    ]
  ]
}
```

rollup.config.json:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.js',
    external: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'styled-components',
      'prop-types',
      'react-icons',
    ],
    output: [
      {
        file: 'dist/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
      },
      {
        file: 'dist/index.es.js',
        format: 'es',
        exports: 'named',
      },
    ],

    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      alias({
        resolve: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx'],
        entries: [
          {
            find: '@src',
            replacement: './src',
          },
          {
            find: '@components',
            replacement: './src/components',
          },
          {
            find: '@utils',
            replacement: './src/utils',
          },
        ],
      }),
      resolve({
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.mjs', '.json'],
        browser: true,
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        plugins: [
          [
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
            { ssr: true, displayName: true, preprocess: false },
          ],
          [
            'module-resolver',
            {
              alias: {
                '@src': ['./src'],
                '@components': ['./src/components'],
                '@utils': ['./src/utils'],
              },
            },
          ],
        ],
        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
        babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      }),
      commo.njs(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
];
```

package.json:

```
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.mjs",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@cypress/react": "^7.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^4.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.13",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@storybook/testing-react": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "cypress": "^11.2.0",
    "eslint": "8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "rollup": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": ">=15.8.1",
    "react": ">=18.2.0",
    "react-dom": ">=18.2.0",
    "react-icons": ">=4.6.0",
    "styled-components": ">=5.3.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "test:cypress": "cypress open"
  },
  "author": "Victoria",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I tried changing my babel and rollup configs, not using "babel-plugin-styled-components" and it did cause another error "e.div is not a fucntion". As I undrestood myself not using this plugin cause it (I might be wrong). So I started using "babel-plugin-styled-components" and now I'm having this issue.

I would be really greatfull if somebody could help me out here.